# Horizontal concatenating dataframes without taking into account the index

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I'm stucked with womething chich looks super easy:

I have a dafatframe df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25, size=(4, 4)),
                   index=["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                   columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wvIM.png)

I have another dafatframe df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25, size=(4, 2)),
                   index=["5", "6", "7", "8"],
                   columns=["A", "F"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYugP.png)

They dont have the same index but I want to concatenate them so that I have something like this:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25, size=(4, 6)),
                   index=["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                   columns=["A", "B", "C", "D","A","F"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KZF8.png)

I don't care about the index, it may be df1's index or something else.

I tried different codes but such as

```
horizontal_concat_init_index = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(df1.index)
```

or

```
horizontal_concat_ignore_index = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

I don't know what to do, I'm lost, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately ignore_index only works on the axis you are trying to concat (which should be axis 1). You could remove the index before the concat:

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```